# How to fix a toolbar missing from the material ui package

Tags: material-ui

Please the toolbar is missing in my material ui....I tried using it and it said export 'ToolBar' (imported as 'ToolBar') was not found in '@mui/material' what do should I do please?

I started afresh still no change

Answer (score 0):

It is Toolbar instead of ToolBar.

import Toolbar from "@mui/material";